# getline does not take any input

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, getline

I need to use getline to store whole line when user enters name and surname. When I run the program, it passes row of getline(cin,st[i].name); I mean the input function does not work, it skips next cin which is for "score".

```
struct Student {
    string name;
    int score;
    char grade;
};

void main() {
    int SIZE;
    cout << " How many students are you going to add ? ";
    cin >> SIZE;
    Student* st = new Student[SIZE]; // user determines size of array.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {   
        if (st[i].name.empty()) // if array list of name is empty, take input.
        {
            cout << "name and surname : ";
            //cin >> st[i].name;
            getline(cin, st[i].name);
        }
        cout << "Score : ";
        cin >> st[i].score; // take quiz score from user.
```

-- I did not put whole main function.

So when l run the program, back screen is shown 
[image: like this]

Is there any other way to get input for name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `cin >> SIZE;`, the trailing newline is still kept in standard input.

You need `cin.ignore()` to skip the remaining newline character so the later `getline()` could get the value.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works but I have one more question. Should I also use cin.clear() ? or do I need to write cin.ignore(1000, '\n') instead of () ?

Comment: Well, you could write `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after you `#include <limits>`. That will successfully ignore as much characters are left in the stream.